# In beamer, how to force `enumerate` and `itemize` labels to be inside the environment they are mentioned in?

Tags: beamer, enumerate, mdframed

In the picture below, there is a custom frame defined using `mdframed` package. It is clear that the enumerations go outside the framed box.

[image]

When similar content is typeset with a normal class, the labels go inside `mdframed` environment.

[image]

I would like to get the same output except for label customization except that the label indentation is aligned with the text above it starting with 'what'.

MWE

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}


\usecolortheme{rose}

\useoutertheme[]{split}

\useinnertheme{inmargin}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    \setbeamersize{text margin left=2mm, text margin right=2mm}

    \newlength{\sidebarWidth}
    \setlength{\sidebarWidth}{0.1\paperwidth}

    \setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\sidebarWidth, sidebar width right=0cm}

% END_FOLD

\usefonttheme{structurebold}



% ==========================================================================
% BEGIN_FOLD


% ========== Package editing packages ==========
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    \AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\centering}
    \BeforeBeginEnvironment{multicols}{\centering}

% END_FOLD
\usepackage{xpatch}

% ========== Figures and tables locations packages ==========
\usepackage{adjustbox}


% ========== Page, margins and paragraph layout packages packages ==========
\usepackage{ragged2e}

% ========== Graphics packages ==========
\usepackage{graphicx}

% ========== Font encoding packages ==========
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% ========== Equations and math packages ==========
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% ========== Framing packages ==========
\usepackage{mdframed}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    % ===== Begin skipbelow patch =====
    \makeatletter
    \xpatchcmd{\endmdframed}
    {\aftergroup\endmdf@trivlist\color@endgroup}
    {\endmdf@trivlist\color@endgroup\@doendpe}
    {}{}
    \makeatother
    % ===== End skipbelow patch =====

    % ===== Frames templates =====
    \newcommand{\frameMultipleChoiceQuiz}{Example Frame}
    \global \mdfdefinestyle{\frameMultipleChoiceQuiz}{
        % Line
        linecolor=DodgerBlue1, linewidth=0.5mm,
        topline=false, bottomline=false, rightline=false,
        skipabove=0.2\baselineskip, skipbelow=0.1\baselineskip,
        innertopmargin=0.5\baselineskip, innerbottommargin=0.5\baselineskip, innerleftmargin=2mm, innerrightmargin=0.01\textwidth,
        %
        % Frame
        frametitlerule=false, frametitlerulewidth=0.2mm
        frametitlefont=\normalsize\bfseries, frametitlealignment=\justifying,
        frametitleaboveskip=1.76mm, frametitlebelowskip=0mm,
        nobreak=false, needspace=3\baselineskip
    }

% END_FOLD


\usepackage{multicol}

% END_FOLD


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Showing Contents Gradually}

    \begin{columns}

        \column[c]{0.4\textwidth}


        \begin{mdframed}[style=\frameMultipleChoiceQuiz]

            What is $\sqrt{x^{2}}$?

            \begin{enumerate}
                \item $X$
                \item $-X$ 
                \item $\left| X \right|$ \onslide<2->{\textbf{correct answer}}
                \item Undefined
            \end{enumerate}

        \end{mdframed}


        \column[c]{0.5\textwidth}
        \onslide<3>{
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        }

        \onslide<3>{Comment on the image}


    \end{columns}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the `inmargin` theme is that elements like the enumerate items are placed in the sidebar, therefore the theme modifies the `\leftmargini` etc. This can be partially undone as shown in the code below.

Some other points:

- if your beamer version is reasonable new, you don't need `\usepackage{etoolbox}`, beamer now already loads this
- you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer
- using `multicol` with beamer makes little sense, beamer has its own columns mechanism

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}


\usecolortheme{rose}

\useoutertheme{split}

\useinnertheme{inmargin}


\setlength\leftmargini{5ex}
\setlength\leftmarginii{7.5ex}
\setlength\leftmarginiii{7.5ex}

% BEGIN_FOLD

    \setbeamersize{text margin left=2mm, text margin right=2mm}

    \newlength{\sidebarWidth}
    \setlength{\sidebarWidth}{0.1\paperwidth}

    \setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\sidebarWidth, sidebar width right=0cm}

% END_FOLD

\usefonttheme{structurebold}



% ==========================================================================
% BEGIN_FOLD


% ========== Package editing packages ==========
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    \AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\centering}
%    \BeforeBeginEnvironment{multicols}{\centering}

% END_FOLD
\usepackage{xpatch}

% ========== Figures and tables locations packages ==========
\usepackage{adjustbox}


% ========== Page, margins and paragraph layout packages packages ==========
\usepackage{ragged2e}

% ========== Graphics packages ==========
%\usepackage{graphicx}

% ========== Font encoding packages ==========
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% ========== Equations and math packages ==========
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% ========== Framing packages ==========
\usepackage{mdframed}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    % ===== Begin skipbelow patch =====
    \makeatletter
    \xpatchcmd{\endmdframed}
    {\aftergroup\endmdf@trivlist\color@endgroup}
    {\endmdf@trivlist\color@endgroup\@doendpe}
    {}{}
    \makeatother
    % ===== End skipbelow patch =====

    % ===== Frames templates =====
    \newcommand{\frameMultipleChoiceQuiz}{Example Frame}
    \global \mdfdefinestyle{\frameMultipleChoiceQuiz}{
        % Line
        linecolor=DodgerBlue1, linewidth=0.5mm,
        topline=false, bottomline=false, rightline=false,
        skipabove=0.2\baselineskip, skipbelow=0.1\baselineskip,
        innertopmargin=0.5\baselineskip, innerbottommargin=0.5\baselineskip, innerleftmargin=2mm, innerrightmargin=0.01\textwidth,
        %
        % Frame
        frametitlerule=false, frametitlerulewidth=0.2mm
        frametitlefont=\normalsize\bfseries, frametitlealignment=\justifying,
        frametitleaboveskip=1.76mm, frametitlebelowskip=0mm,
        nobreak=false, needspace=3\baselineskip
    }

% END_FOLD


%\usepackage{multicol}

% END_FOLD


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Showing Contents Gradually}

    \begin{columns}

        \column[c]{0.4\textwidth}


        \begin{mdframed}[style=\frameMultipleChoiceQuiz]

            What is $\sqrt{x^{2}}$?

            \begin{enumerate}
                \item $X$
                \item $-X$ 
                \item $\left| X \right|$ \onslide<2->{\textbf{correct answer}}
                \item Undefined
            \end{enumerate}

        \end{mdframed}


        \column[c]{0.5\textwidth}
        \onslide<3>{
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        }

        \onslide<3>{Comment on the image}


    \end{columns}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still new to `beamer` but also an advanced LaTeX user. I think a better variation to your solution is to use `\AtBeginEnvironment{mdframed}{\setlength{\leftmargini}{5ex}}` which will customize `\leftmargini` variable only for `mdframed`. Similar codes can be used for other envitonments where we want to change  `\leftmargini` `\leftmarginii` and `\leftmarginiii`

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Of course you can make the changes locally if you only want to change certain enumerations

Comment: I think you know a lot about beamer and its layouts. Why do not you create a new package similar to `geometry` but made specifically to provide easy customization for `beamer` frames layouts and enumeration environments indentations and seperations?